# Склонение числительных

Tags: лингвистика

"Почему-то в предыдущих несколько тысяч сообщениях это правило не действовало". Правильно ли составлено это предложение? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, выражение построено неправильно. Тут числительное склоняется. Правильно будет: "Почему-то в предыдущих нескольк**их** тысяч**ах** сообщений это правило не действовало".

Answer (score 0):

"Почему-то в предыдущих несколькИХ тысячАХ сообщениях это правило не действовало".
По - моему, похожий случай со склонением неопределённого местоимения НЕСКОЛЬКО уже разбирался. (См. “По несколько раз” или “по нескольку”? )                                                   Р.п. - чего? несколькИХ, Д.п. - чему? несколькИМ, Т.п. - чем? несколькИМИ, П.п. - о чём? о несколькИХ? Местоименное числительное "несколько" склоняется как прилагательное, а существительное "тысяча" как существительное 1 склонения.